# Creating unique pages of a website by passing an sql key

Tags: php, html, sql

The title may be a bit awful as I'm really not sure how to describe what I'm trying to achieve without using lots of words.

I'm currently building an events website. This website has the option for users to create their own events which can be added to a big list of upcoming events that other users have submitted.

What I want to do is be able to have a user create an event and have the details of the event stored in an SQL database (which I've successfully done), I  want to be able to then have a large list of events on a separate page the details of which are pulled from the server dynamically using PHP and SQL (I've also successfully done this). The part I am struggling with however is being able to create unique pages (or a single dynamic page) that displays a more detailed look at the event, such as age restrictions etc etc, which cannot be displayed on the big list which displays all the available events.

I figured that this could be done using a unique eventID, which is something the SQL database already includes and autoincrements with each new event entry. What I'm really not sure about is how I'd be able to pass that eventID through the link to the more detailed page so that the detailed page can be created displaying all of the details of the event.

I'm not even sure if this idea will work at all. Would having a page with a unique URL that is created on event submission that has a more in-depth look at the details of the event be a better idea? How would I go about creating unique URL webpages that correspond to each event on event submission?

I'm really not sure how I need to go about this at all, so I need some help and pointing in the right direction.

Here's a kind of TLDR:

1) Events website

2) All events on the website are displayed on a single page that has minimal detail about each event (title, date, location) BUT has a link to a page that displays the event in more detail.

3) User can select an event from the list and click on that event's unique HTML link to more detailed page

4) More detailed page displays event in more detail by pulling event's unique information from the database

Feel free to ask any questions at all as I know this probably isn't the easiest idea to get across

Comment: While this is awfully broad you would start by getting all of the data associated with an event and creating a page which would display all of the details. You already know how to do that if you're able to create a page with less information.

Comment: I already have a page that displays all of the detail of each event. What I need to be able to do is create a unique page for each event that is submitted by a user

Answer (score 0):

When creating the links from the general listing page to the detail page, simply include the id in the link. For example:

```
<A HREF="mysite.com/detail.php?id=3>Big Event</A>
```

In `detail.php` then, you'll find the id in `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: This might just be what I needed, but how do I create unique webpages on submission of the create event form?

Comment: That's a little difficult to answer without knowing what all you know. You've managed to put together a general listing page, so you know how to construct a page from data you've retrieved from the database. This is the same principle. Just perform your query based on the id that was passed, to retrieve the event data, then construct your detail page from that.